# Django model FilterSet - choose database and update filter fields from view

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter, django-tables2

I have a Django application working with multiple databases of the same structure. Database name is a part of the url so it comes as an argument into the view (`self.kwargs['db']`). I use `django-tables2` along with `django-filter` to show  table data (`SingleTableMixin, FilterView`). I need to set which database has to be used to populate the filter's fields. The filter uses the default one at the moment.

filters.py

```
class FooFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['project', 'fooclass']
```

views.py

```
class FilteredFooView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    template_name = "metadata/metadata-filtered-table.html"
    table_pagination = False
    table_class = FooTable
    model = Foo
    filterset_class = FooFilter
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Foo.objects.using(self.kwargs['db']).all() # sets db for the table

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        template_input = {'item': 'FooItem', 'name': getName(self.kwargs['db'])}
        context = {**template_input, **context, **self.kwargs}
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the db name in the kwargs,
and then use it during the **init** of the FilterSet

some helpful info here; https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#request-based-filtering

```py
class FilteredFooView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    template_name = "metadata/metadata-filtered-table.html"
    table_pagination = False
    table_class = FooTable
    model = Foo
    filterset_class = FooFilter
    
    # pass the db name to the FooFilter
    def get_filterset_kwargs(self, filterset_class)
        kwargs = super(FooFilter, self).get_filterset_kwargs(filterset_class)
        kwargs['db'] = self.kwargs['db']
        return kwargs


class FooFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    # capture the db name
    self.db_ = kwargs.pop['db']
    super(FooFilter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    # override the base queryset
    self.queryset = Foo.objects.using(db_).all()


    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['project', 'fooclass']
```